# Justification of Integrating an $L^1$ Function with Singularity

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The function $f_p:[0,1]\rightarrow \textbf{R}^{\geqslant 0}$, $0<p<\infty$, $f_p(x):=px^{p-1}$ has a singularity at $x=0$. However, it's improper Riemann integral converges, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_h^1\,px^{p-1}\,dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(1-h^p) = 1
\end{align*}
Therefore $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}[0,1]$, but I would like a sanity check that this is sufficient to be in $L^1[0,1]$.

More generally, under what conditions can we ignore singularities when considering $L^p$ functions. If we can make the improper Riemann integral converge  is that always sufficient for being in $L^p$?

Comment: One criteria is assume f is nonnegative and apply Monotone Convergence Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with a finite improper Riemanm inetgral need not be in $L^{1}$. An example is $\frac {\sin x} x$ on $(0,\infty)$. However, if  a non-negative measurable function has an improper Riemann integral then it is in $L^{1}$ by Monotone Convergence Theorem.